# Solving an arithmetic expression with multiple answers (Vietnamese Math Maze)

Tags: prolog

I have to try and solve this Vietnamese math challenge (https://www.theguardian.com/science/alexs-adventures-in-numberland/2015/may/20/can-you-do-the-maths-puzzle-for-vietnamese-eight-year-olds-that-has-stumped-parents-and-teachers) using prolog and I've been really stumped as to how to write the predicate. Here's the question:

> Assume ordinary rules of arithmetic precedence (i.e.
>   multiplication/division before addition/subtraction). The answers
>   should be in the form of a list of digits which would be entered into
>   the blanks in the maze from left to right. Name the predicate mathmaze
>   and have it take one argument, which gets instantiated as the correct
>   list of numbers (and gives other answers when prompted with ;).

This is what I have so far, but I have no idea how to actually how to have it try 1-9 in each position of the equation.

```
mathmaze([H|T]) :-
   A + ((13* B) / C) + D + (12 * E) - F - 11 + G * (H / I) - 10 = 66.
```

Comment: cheating: `?- Vs=[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I], Vs ins 0 .. 100, A + ((13 * B) // C) + D + (12 * E) - F - 11 + G * (H // I) - 10 #= 66, label(Vs).
Vs = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 87, 1],
A = B, B = D, D = E, E = F, F = 0,
C = G, G = I, I = 1,
H = 87 ;...`

Comment: Why does the scale go from 0-100?

Comment: It's the *domain*, not scale. An arbitrary choice, just because label/1 requires it

Comment: Why the grouping `G*(H/I)` rather than `(G*H)/I`?

Answer (score 1):

```
mathmaze([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I]) :-
    permutation([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I]),
    66 is (A + ((13 * B) / C) + D + (12 * E) - F - 11 + (G * (H / I)) - 10).
```

This says:

- Take a list of 9 variables
- Make the list of variables a permutation of the list composed of 1 to 9.
- Check that the variables evaluate (using is) to 66.

This could be written using CLPFD, but it doesn't provide any non-integer division, so it will generate false answers, and for a problem as tightly defined as this, replacing permutation with [all_distinct/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=all_distinct/1) and [ins/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=ins/2) doesn't seem worth the effort (but CLPFD is certainly a useful library for this style of problem in general).

Comment: You may be able to get rid of the divisions my multiplying both sides of the equation appropriately, making integer constraints applicable.

Answer (score 1):

## Applying CLP(FD) constraints

First, a general note: When reasoning over **integers** in Prolog, I highly recommend you use your system's **CLP(FD) constraints**.

As @JimAshworth correctly points out, such constraints only work over *integers*, and in particular do not provide *division* with fractional results.

*However*, we can often, and also in this case, easily circumvent such divisions by applying purely **algebraic transformations**.

In this case, I can eliminate the division

> ```
> A/B #= C
> ```

by simply writing *instead*:

> ```
> A #= B*C
> ```

Algebraically, I have simply multiplied *both sides* of the equation with `B`.

## Solution

Hence, a possible solution could look like this:

```
mathmaze(Vs) :-
        Vs = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I],
        Vs ins 1..9,
        all_different(Vs),
          A*C*I + 13*B*I + D*C*I + 12*E*C*I
        - F*C*I - 11*C*I + G*C*H - 10*C*I #= 66*C*I.
```

Sample query and result:

```
?- mathmaze(Vs), time(labeling([ff], Vs)).
% 5,869,675 inferences, 7.221 CPU in 7.243 seconds (100% CPU, 812897 Lips)
Vs = [1, 2, 6, 4, 7, 8, 3, 5, 9] .
```

## Correctness

Let us now use the other posted formulation to **test** this result. With the accepted answer, we get:

```
?- mathmaze([1, 2, 6, 4, 7, 8, 3, 5, 9]).
false.
```

So, which is it: Is this a solution or not?

Judging from what little floating point numbers can help us, it *may* be a solution:

```
?- X is 1+13*2/6+4+12*7-8-11+3*(5/9)-10.
X = 66.0.
```

Of course, floating point numbers are of extremely limited help in such cases, and so we use **rational numbers** instead:

```
?- X is  1+13*(2 rdiv 6) +4+12*7-8-11+3*(5 rdiv 9)-10.
X = 66.
```

*Yes*, it's a solution! However, since the accepted answer uses *floating point numbers*, it is not recognized as such, because:

```
?- 66 is 66.0.
false.
```

That's right! 66.0 is *not* 66. Welcome to the pioneering technology of the 1940s.

In total, the accepted answer **misses 136 solutions** due to the use of floating point numbers. However, since it *does find* a few solutions (6 in total), such mistakes are easy to overlook. To be on the safe side, I recommend you *always* use integers, rational numbers, or a similarly *safe* representation when reasoning about numbers in Prolog.